# How does Google Analytics apply userid to the session if the user logs off?

Tags: google-analytics

We have a view set up with userid reports enabled. When the user logs out, our developer set our web page up to fire a null userid. I'm trying to determine whether the updated userid set to null is overwriting the entire session which is then being dropped from the view.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: No it does not overwrite the entire session if you send a blank value but I would suggest to not send it as blank either as GA will ignore the hit if you do so, if you have it you include it otherwise just omit it.

There's a feature called [session unification](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/4574780) that should clarify what happens when you have it on/off and what happens when you have a value in the userid field and when you don't.